# Cannot upload firestore cloud function with wildcard and onDelete trigger?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a function with trigger like so:

```
exports.eventDeleteListener = functions.firestore.document('events/{eid}').onDelete((doc, context) => {
```

And when I try to upload to Google cloud functions I am met with the following error:

*Failed to configure trigger PubSub projects/myprojectstringthingy*

I have similar functions with this same document path, but with an `onUpdate` trigger like so:

```
exports.isDeletingFlagListener = functions.firestore.document('events/{eid}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
```

And these all deploy and work perfectly fine. This function has deployed previously. However, after updating node and firebase tools this function will no longer deploy. I believe it has something to do with rules, as per documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started), however I do not understand why the other function triggers deploy.

If needed, I can paste the entire function in question.

UPDATE:
I tried deleting all cloud functions and re deploying. I am getting the same error message for four of the functions now, however they are appearing on firestore console as deployed?

Comment: I suggest contacting Firebase support if you're unable to deploy, and you don't get an actionable error message.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks I'll do that and update

Answer (score 1):

I have a test project that I successfully deployed functions to yesterday. I deleted them and tried redeploying the exact same ones and got your error as well. So the problem seems to be something at Firebase.

Comment: I just clean deleted all of my current functions and tried to re deploy all of them. Now four of them are returning with the same error. But they appear on the firestore console as successfully deployed?

Comment: Same for me. Now it's 24 hours later and deploying works fine again. I guess this will be true for you as well. The only thing you can do in this situation is report it to Firebase support.

Comment: It is now working for me too. Unfortunately I cannot mark as the answer because it did not fix the issue, but I did upvote because it was helpful.

Comment: No problem, I hope it can help someone in the future!